# I have an ampersand in my user profile name and it wont let me run the code I am writing. how do I remove the ampersand?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
At line:1 char:16
+ C:\Users\Lucas & Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python ...
+                ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

This is the error I keep getting when I exe my code. I have tried just changing my user name but the `c:\user\Lucas & Rachel` still shows in command prompt and in vs code. Is this the issue? or am I missing something?

this is the code i am trying to run

```
import turtle 
def drawBoard() 
   for i in range(2): 
drawer.penup() 
drawer.goto(-300, 100 - 200 *i) 
drawer.pendown() 
drawer.forward(600) 
drawer = turtle.Turtle() 
drawer.pensize(10) 
drawer.ht() 
screen = turtle.Screen() 
screen.tracer(0) 
drawBoard()
```

now i am getting this,

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS D:\Tic Tac Toe Test> & "C:/Users/Lucas & Rachel/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "d:/Tic Tac Toe Test/test.py"
  File "d:\Tic Tac Toe Test\test.py", line 4
    def drawBoard
```

Comment: Could you please add the code snippet of the code which causes the error?

Comment: import turtle


def drawBoard()

    for i in range(2):
        drawer.penup()
        drawer.goto(-300, 100 - 200 *i)
        drawer.pendown()
        drawer.forward(600)
    


drawer = turtle.Turtle()

drawer.pensize(10)
drawer.ht()

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

drawBoard()

Comment: Can you just wrap the entire User Name in single quotes?  But it isn't clear how you are using it.

Comment: what is the command to wrap the name in single quotes? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: @Lamb Is this the real snippet? If yes, it's strange, because the output says, that the error has occurred at the 1st line, and ```import turtle``` seems to have nothing to do with it. It may be the setting of your IDE (VS Code). Try to launch the program from the command line.

Comment: @Lamb please fix your indentations with your recent revision.

Comment: @Lamb, wrapping it in single quotes means pressing the quote key on the keyboard once before the string, and once after, like this: `'some string with spaces'`. Paths and other strings with spaces or special chars must have quotes around them to prevent problems.

Comment: In programming, it is good practice to use paths to code which have NO spaces and NO special chars, to prevent problems like this. In the future, when creating a user account, use `Lucas_and_Rachel` instead of `Lucas & Rachel`.

Comment: Gabriel, is it possible to change my user account name to Lucas_and_Rachel? i had no plans on coding when i got this compuer hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, file addresses don't like spaces. You could try wrapping the entire address in double quotes:
"C:\Users\Lucas & Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python"

Sometimes you can use a ^ (carot) to as an escape character to use before each space and special character...

C:\Users\Lucas^ ^&^ Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python

you may have to use that in combination with double quotes. I have not used a windows machine in a while